# How to calculate the polarity of sentimental scores in sentiment analysis

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, polarization

I extracted the comments and calculated the sentimental score using the lexicon-based sentiment analysis (-negative ~ +positive).

I was wondering if this is right to try to use min-max scaling to calculate the affective polarization score for each comment. In other words, I want to check if 0 means that the degree of polarization is not large, and 1 means that the degree of polarization is large.

```
demo_df['polarity'] = (demo_df['sentiment_score'] - min_score) / score_range
```

Thank you in advance!!

I wanna get polarity score.

Comment: "right" according to whom / what? [ask]